# In an array, how can I get values printed the way I would like them printed instead of the last value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, for-loop

I am using a `for-loop` to get the values of a sorted list using `.html()` but it is only printing the last value in the array. I thought by using `myArray.length` and `myArray[i]` in the loop that it would cycle through as expected.

Ideally, I would like this to read:

The sorted values are:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc. . .

What am I doing wrong?

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/L2ggsykq/9/)

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Let's Do Some Math</h1>
        <div id="intake">
        <input type="text" id="input"> <button id="inTakeButton">Push to Array</button> <button id="showArray">Show Array</button> <button id="doMath">Do Math</button>
        </div>
        <div id="middle">
            <ul id="list">
            </ul>
    </div>
        <div id="output">
            <p id="sorted"></p>
            <p id="sum"></p>
            <p id="average"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 3px black;
    padding: 10px;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: orange;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px blue;
}

#intake {
    text-align: center;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
myArray = [];
var theTotal;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#inTakeButton').on('click', function() {
        var inputValue = parseFloat($('#input').val());
        if (inputValue === "") {
            return;
        }
        if (isNaN(inputValue)) {
            $('#input').val("");
            return;
        }
        myArray.push(inputValue);
        $('#input').val("");
    });
    $('#showArray').on('click', function() {
        console.log(myArray);
        $('#list').html("");
        for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            $('#list').append("<li>" + myArray[i] + "</ul>");
        };
        $('#doMath').on('click', function() {
            theTotal = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
              theTotal = theTotal + myArray[i];  
            };
            $('#sum').html("");
            $('#sum').html("The sum is: " + theTotal);
            var average = (theTotal/myArray.length);
            $('#average').html("");
            $('#average').html("The mean value is: " + average);
            var sorted = myArray.sort();
            $('#sorted').html("");
            for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
             $('#sorted').html("The sorted values are: <br>" + myArray[i] + ", ");   
            };
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You have a tag mismatch: $('#list').append("<li>" + myArray[i] + "</ul>");

Comment: In your loop for the sorted values, you are overriding the entire HTML content each time.

Comment: Just use `$('#sorted').html("The sorted values are: <br>" + sorted ); ` without the loop.

Comment: In your second loop, you use `.html()` not `.append()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't even need to use loop trough the array to do this, just:

```
$('#sorted').html("The sorted values are: <br>" + myArray.join(", "));
```

Comment: Ding! Ding! Ding! We have a winner folks!

Comment: Just to be clear, does using `.join(", ")` only join the comma when it's printed and the array is kept as numbers only?

Comment: That's correct. `.join()` loops trough your array and return a string, without modifying the original array.

Answer (score 2):

In your loop for the sorted values, you are overriding the entire HTML content each time.

Try something like

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
     $('#sorted').append(myArray[i] + ", ");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. Instead of showing the values using a loop, you can just display the whole array at once. Edited JS code:

```
myArray = [];
var theTotal;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#inTakeButton').on('click', function() {
        var inputValue = parseFloat($('#input').val());
        if (inputValue === "") {
            return;
        }
        if (isNaN(inputValue)) {
            $('#input').val("");
            return;
        }
        myArray.push(inputValue);
        $('#input').val("");
    });
    $('#showArray').on('click', function() {
        console.log(myArray);
        $('#list').html("");
        for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            $('#list').append("<li>" + myArray[i] + "</ul>");
        };
        $('#doMath').on('click', function() {
            theTotal = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
              theTotal = theTotal + myArray[i];  
            };
            $('#sum').html("");
            $('#sum').html("The sum is: " + theTotal);
            var average = (theTotal/myArray.length);
            $('#average').html("");
            $('#average').html("The mean value is: " + average);
            var sorted = myArray.sort();
            $('#sorted').html("The sorted values are: <br>" + myArray )
        });
    });
});
```

Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2ggsykq/12/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var sorted =  myArray.sort(function (a, b) {
   return a - b;
});
```

use this for sorting